# Google Cloud Storage same file name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using this with angluar and flow.js to upload images but im running into the problem that when the file names are the same it doesn't complete and i don't understand why. shouldn't it just overwrite the previous one.

```
class ImageUploadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        chunk_number = int(self.request.params.get('flowChunkNumber'))
        chunk_size = int(self.request.params.get('flowChunkSize'))
        current_chunk_size = int(self.request.params.get('flowCurrentChunkSize'))
        total_size = int(self.request.params.get('flowTotalSize'))
        total_chunks = int(self.request.params.get('flowTotalChunks'))
        identifier = str(self.request.params.get('flowIdentifier'))
        filename = str(self.request.params.get('flowFilename'))
        data = self.request.params.get('file')

        f = ImageFile(filename, identifier, total_chunks, chunk_size, total_size)
        f.write_chunk(chunk_number, current_chunk_size, data)

        if f.ready_to_build():
            info = f.build()
            if info:
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                self.response.out.write(json.dumps(info.as_dict()))
            else:
                self.error(500)
        else:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            self.response.out.write(json.dumps({
                'chunkNumber': chunk_number,
                'chunkSize': chunk_size,
                'message': 'Chunk ' + str(chunk_number) + ' written'
            }))
```

Where ImageFile is a class that writes to the google cloud storage.

Edit:

Below the ImageFile class. Only thing missing is the FileInfo class which is a simple model to store the generated url with the filename.

```
class ImageFile:
    def __init__(self, filename, identifier, total_chunks, chunk_size, total_size):
        self.bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME', app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
        self.original_filename = filename
        self.filename = '/' + self.bucket_name + '/' + self.original_filename
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.total_chunks = total_chunks
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.total_size = total_size
        self.stat = None
        self.chunks = []
        self.load_stat()
        self.load_chunks(identifier, total_chunks)

    def load_stat(self):
        try:
            self.stat = gcs.stat(self.filename)
        except gcs.NotFoundError:
            self.stat = None

    def load_chunks(self, identifier, number_of_chunks):
        for n in range(1, number_of_chunks + 1):
            self.chunks.append(Chunk(self.bucket_name, identifier, n))

    def exists(self):
        return not not self.stat

    def content_type(self):
        if self.filename.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            return 'image/jpeg'
        elif self.filename.lower().endswith('.jpeg'):
            return 'image/jpeg'
        elif self.filename.lower().endswith('.png'):
            return 'image/png'
        elif self.filename.lower().endswith('.git'):
            return 'image/gif'
        else:
            return 'binary/octet-stream'

    def ready(self):
        return self.exists() and self.stat.st_size == self.total_size

    def ready_chunks(self):
        for c in self.chunks:
            if not c.exists():
                return False
        return True

    def delete_chunks(self):
        for c in self.chunks:
            c.delete()

    def ready_to_build(self):
        return not self.ready() and self.ready_chunks()

    def write_chunk(self, chunk_number, current_chunk_size, data):
        chunk = self.chunks[int(chunk_number) - 1]
        chunk.write(current_chunk_size, data)

    def build(self):
        try:
            log.info('File \'' + self.filename + '\': assembling chunks.')
            write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
            gcs_file = gcs.open(self.filename,
                                'w',
                                content_type=self.content_type(),
                                options={'x-goog-meta-identifier': self.identifier},
                                retry_params=write_retry_params)
            for c in self.chunks:
                log.info('Writing chunk ' + str(c.chunk_number) + ' of ' + str(self.total_chunks))
                c.write_on(gcs_file)
            gcs_file.close()
        except Exception, e:
            log.error('File \'' + self.filename + '\': Error during assembly - ' + e.message)
        else:
            self.delete_chunks()
            key = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + self.filename)
            url = images.get_serving_url(key)
            info = ImageInfo(name=self.original_filename, url=url)
            info.put()
            return info
```

The Chunk class:

```
class Chunk:
    def __init__(self, bucket_name, identifier, chunk_number):
        self.chunk_number = chunk_number
        self.filename = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + identifier + '-chunk-' + str(chunk_number)
        self.stat = None
        self.load_stat()

    def load_stat(self):
        try:
            self.stat = gcs.stat(self.filename)
        except gcs.NotFoundError:
            self.stat = None

    def exists(self):
        return not not self.stat

    def write(self, size, data):
        write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
        gcs_file = gcs.open(self.filename, 'w', retry_params=write_retry_params)
        for c in data.file:
            gcs_file.write(c)
        gcs_file.close()
        self.load_stat()

    def write_on(self, stream):
        gcs_file = gcs.open(self.filename)

        try:
            data = gcs_file.read()
            while data:
                stream.write(data)
                data = gcs_file.read()
        except gcs.Error, e:
            log.error('Error writing data to chunk: ' + e.message)
        finally:
            gcs_file.close()

    def delete(self):
        try:
            gcs.delete(self.filename)
            self.stat = None
        except gcs.NotFoundError:
            pass
```